# Historical data for success rate of grant/project applications?

Tags: funding

Is there any publicly accessible information regarding the success rate of grant/project applications for science/technology and other research grant programs (e.g. NSF grants) and its variation over time?

I'm not interested in an exhaustive list but some illustrative examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: here is a link I found from the NIH titled "Success Rates - NIH" : https://report.nih.gov/success_rates/index.aspx

in addition, if I remember correctly, about 10% of all proposals are funded AND that about 30% of proposals were from first time proposers. I will look for the reference to both of these statistics. I believe they were from a lynda.com course for educational grants, which has great information for this topic: https://www.lynda.com/Higher-Education-tutorials/Grant-Writing-Education/196581-2.html

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [NIH Research Portfolio Online Reporting Tools](http://report.nih.gov/success_rates/index.aspx). It may take you some time to find exactly what you're looking for, but there are numerous reports available, with a good deal of detail.

Answer (score 3):

It's surprisingly hard to find that information, I was expecting to get it more easily, in particular when public funding is involved. I've found for the European Union FP7-ICT call 1, there were 1836 proposals for only 318 accepted, with a total 1.2 billion euros funded ([Source, slide 18](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/jrc/downloads/enlargement/infodays/jrc_20080506_infoday_tirana_cindy_vd_boogert.pdf)).

I guess a good strategy could be to contact the [Research Division](http://ec.europa.eu/research/index.cfm?pg=contacts&lg=en) of the European Commission, I'm sure they have this information somewhere, and they are probably able to provide it.

Comment: And if you actually find the information, I'd be glad to have it :)

Comment: me too! did you find it?

Comment: @flow: No, I didn't really look for it :)